# video using FLVPlayback does not work in .exe mode

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm building a flash desktop app with several frames, one of which have a video, i used the FLVPlayback that i found in the library, added my video to it. It works fine when i compile the file in a SWF format, but when i compile it in a .exe format, when i arrive at the frame that has the video i get a black screen, i did some research and found that the problem is that my app is full screen:

```
//i have this code in frame 1
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

so the solution they suggested is to add the folowing code in the frame that contains the video:

```
myPlayer.fullScreenTakeOver = false;
```

i tried it and still, no changes. any idea why this happens?

Comment: If I remember correctly, in projector you are to use **fscommand** to go into fullscreen mode rather than anything else: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/package.html

Comment: What makes you think fullscreen is the problem?   Have you tried using the debug flash player to check for errors?   Is the video you're playing embedded in the SWF, or loaded from the file system?

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure that the video is in the same folder with your other files. Also video could be too heavy for this format, so you can try to reduce it's weight.